# Unwanted UIView over UICollectionViewCell (TapGesture Doesn't work )

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Recently, I see a strange thing in Xcode 11.4.
When I create a UICollectionView with Its cell, adding TapGesture doesn't work. By debugging on its view in runtime, I noticed a view covers all the cells. It seems it is ContainerView.
This view prevents users to click or tap on items.
Any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding your subviews and tap gesture to the cell's contentView?

In the documentation for UICollectionViewCell (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell), it says:

> To configure the appearance of your cell, add the views needed to
>   present the data item’s content as subviews to the view in the
>   contentView property. Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself.

The same applies for UITableViewCell as well.